# for loop in Internet Exporer has no value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an old application that didnt use jquery.

`so` is an HTML select object.

This code gives an error, that value is not set in the second line of:

```
for (var i in so.options){
        if(so.options[i].value=='X') {
            // do something
        }
}
```

It works in Firefox though. How can I catch this without jquery?

Comment: What type of object is `so.options`?

Comment: Read this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) and this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Mathieu Amiot's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea):

> You can also be clever. `for(var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; ++i)`
>   ... is the fastest and best you can get with forward iteration.

So my solution for IE and FF:

```
for(var i = 0, l = so.options.length; i < l; ++i){
    if(so.options[i].value=='X') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the first property of `so.options` is the `.length` property, which is numeric and not an object.

To iterate an [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection), you need to do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < so.options.length; ++i) {
    if (so.options.item(i).value == 'X') {
    }
}
```

Most browsers will probably provide a convenience accessor, though, so `so.options[i].value` should work as well.

Comment: Where's the i++ in the loop?

Comment: I was going to edit it but you've disabled it. Sure no problem.

Comment: @geekpradd I didn't disable anything, it's probably due to your reputation score being too low to suggest edits?